# Can't Import GDAL

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, gdal

I have installed GDAL and it's showing in `pip show GDAL` and `pip list`, the location of GDAL in `sys.path` is showing as well ('C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages'), but I can import it neither in VS Code nor in the default IDLE. I am using Python 3.10.

the GDAL info from `pip show GDAL` is as follows:

> Name: GDAL Version: 3.3.3
> Summary: GDAL: Geospatial Data Abstraction
> Library Home-page: http://www.gdal.org
> Author: Frank Warmerdam
> Author-email: warmerdam@pobox.com
> License: MIT
> Location: c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages
> Requires:
> Required-by:

Comment: You say you cannot import it - what error do you get, or why do you think you can't import it?

Comment: This is the error I am getting-
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Py.py", line 1, in <module>
    import GDAL
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'GDAL'

Comment: Have you tried `gdal`? Python is case-sensitive. Or `from osgeo import gdal` depending on what packages you have installed exactly.

Comment: Very Sorry for the delay,, yes from osgeo it is working

Comment: You're not sharing the code that shows how you import it, which you say isn't working. Please add that code example to the question. My suggestion was that you may have capitalised `GDAL` in your code, just like you did in the command line example that you did share - and that wouldn't work.

Comment: Thank you no I was trying all small letters but not with osgeo. I tried to `pip install gdal ` which worked but `import gdal` was not working. Then I tried `from osgeo import gdal` which then worked.

Comment: OK, it sounds like you problem was resolved? That's great, but you should either close your question if you no longer require an answer, or put a brief description of your own answer in an answer to your own question, and accept it. That way, the question stays up, but no longer shows up as unanswered on SO.